# What is the difference between boilerplate code and API?

Tags: java

I was just googling and get to know about Boilerplate code. But what is the difference between the boilerplate code and API , are they same in any kind ?
Or they totally different from each other ?

Comment: Two seconds of searching ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Comment: Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help), which will explain what subjects are considered on topic for this site, and will show you how to ask good questions which receive good answers. Generally speaking, good questions are those which address *specific programming issues*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boilerplate code refers to the code that sets up a particular type of project. For example, if you're creating a new web application using ReactJS, the "boilerplate code" would consist of an `App.js` file and some other pre-written code.

An API is somewhat unrelated (although common APIs might have boilerplate code). API stands for Application Program Interface, and is basically a way for your program to interact with another program. For example, the Google Maps API provides methods for getting routes from point A to point B, which your program can use.

Answer (score 3):

Boilerplate code and API are two different things.

Boilerplate code is common patterns of code that you must write to accomplish a given task. Often this is the code required just to get a running program. For example in Java, you must declare a class with a `main()` method at the very least.

An API, on the other hand, is a library which some other programmer has written and you can use often with much less typing than you would otherwise. For example, Java has a Collections API which provides common data structures such as `ArrayList` and `HashMap`. These are very time consuming to write yourself and debug.

In a sense, boilerplate code and API are opposites. Writing boilerplate code takes a significant amount of time to write with very little useful gain. Using an API greatly increases your productivity as a programmer by leveraging someone else's code that has been used by many other programmers and had many of the bugs found and fixed.